# How can I use PUT method with PrestaShopWebservice

Tags: php, web-services, web, prestashop, put

Currently I'm trying to update or make a new record of stock_availables using the presashop Webservice, however, after create/up (within of prestashop backoffice admin view) all the functionallity of the stock_availables WebService (Checking the checkbox for to create all CRUD Endpoints of the webservice), which means all the crud *WS.

This method ( POST ) looks does not work fine, **I have tried to use the next chunk of code :**

```
//NOWE WE NEED TO ADD OUR PRODUCT IN A STOCK_AVAILABLE
function addStockAvailable( $id_created_product, $quantity  ) {
    $key_stock_availabe  = 'TIN3JMGSEETG5436ISGS3J452GIMDNYE';
    try {
        $psXML = <<<XML
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <stock_available>
            <id></id>
            <id_product>$id_created_product</id_product>
            <id_product_attribute></id_product_attribute>
            <id_shop>1</id_shop> <!--daytech id shop = 1 --> 
            <id_shop_group></id_shop_group>
            <quantity>$quantity</quantity>
            <depends_on_stock></depends_on_stock>
            <out_of_stock></out_of_stock>
            <location></location>
        </stock_available>
    </prestashop>
    XML;

    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, $key_stock_availabe, DEBUG);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($psXML);
    $opt = array( 'resource' => 'stock_availables' );
    $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
    $xml = $webService->add( $opt );
    echo "alta de stock disponible (STOCK_AVAILABLE) satisfactoria"; 
    } catch( PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex ) {
        // Shows a message related to the error
        echo 'Other error: <br />' . $ex->getMessage();
        
        $logFile = fopen("../logs/ws_logs.txt", 'a') or die("Error modificando el stock available" );

        fwrite($logFile, "\n".date("d/m/Y H:i:s")." Error STOCK AVAILABLE "
                . $ex->getMessage(). "en la linea " 
                . $ex->getLine() ) or die("Error actualizando stock dinsponible");
        fclose($logFile);
    }
}
```

**to add some amount of stock for my previously registered product, Getting the next error :**
*Other error: 
This call to PrestaShop Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 405. That means: Method Not Allowed - (Code 101): Method POST is not allowed for the resource stock_availables.*

Could you please give a little hand and tellme whats wrongo with my little piece of code ?
Community Thanks A lot for your invaluable support.

Finally it is important to say that I really hope to get some more specific information about how can I use all the methods of the webservices of prestashop, such as: POST, DELTE, GET AND SPECIALLY PUT method.